# Lindemann's proof that $e^{a}$ is transcendental if $a$ is a non-zero algebraic number.

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-numbers

This question is not about lindemann-weierstrass theorem.

In the wikipedia page, it is written that von lindemann first proved the statement I mentioned in the title and later weierstrass generalized it.

There is a proof of lindermann-weierstrass theorem on the wikipedia page but I cannot find the proof of von lindemann's non-generalized statement.

So this question is a request to all the readers to give me the proof in the answers or link me to a site which has the proof.

Comment: While not included in the article itself, the proof is actually provided in the "references" section: Lindemann, F. (1882), "[Über die Ludolph'sche Zahl.](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=YxkYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA391)", *Sitzungsberichte der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin*, **2**: 679–682. It is in German, and I cannot read German.

Comment: Can you give me the english translation of the article.

Comment: See [*Pi is transcendental: Von Lindemann’s proof made accessible to today’s undergraduates*](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~rudol/Pi_TranscendentalLindemann.pdf) by Randy K. Schwartz (2 February 2006).

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question. I asked for a proof of transcendence of $e^{a}$ when a is non-zero and algebraic.

Comment: That paper is short. Use Google Translate to help you with terms you do not know. A few weeks ago I wanted to understand a 2-3 page proof in an old paper of Dedekind. It is not realistic to expect old papers have  English translations somewhere. I used Google Translate and figured everything out myself. You can do it too.

Comment: *I asked for a proof of transcendence of* --- See [**Irrational Numbers**](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/niven.pdf) by Ivan Niven and/or [**Making Transcendence Transparent**](https://www.amazon.com//dp/0387214445) by Burger/Tubbs. Also the first google search I tried, [Lindemann + transcendental + algebraic + nonzero](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lindemann+transcendental+algebraic+nonzero), appears to give many such proofs online (especially if you include [+ .pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=Lindemann+transcendental+algebraic+nonzero+.pdf)), or am I missing something?

Comment: @KCd, actually google translate is not that good at translating big paragraphs . It sometimes gives wrong translations. But let me try first

Comment: In my experience, Google Translate is adequate for translating math.  Not always perfect, but still fine.  Pages 18-20 of Tubbs' "Hilbert's Seventh Problem" outlines a proof of Lindemann's theorem for $e^\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is nonzero and algebraic.